# QA Error while installing tokbox on yocto

Tags: yocto, opentok, tokbox

I'm trying to install Tokbox prebuilt library on Yocto, but I'm getting the following QA error.

```
ERROR: tokbox-2.18.1-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue:
/usr/lib/libopentok.so contained in package tokbox requires
libc++.so.1()(64bit), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_tokbox?
[file-rdeps]
```

Thanks,
VR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understood, libc++ is a new implementation of the C++ standard library that is coming from LLVM/clang. You then need to add `meta-clang` layer to your `bblayers.conf` (after having it cloned obviously) and add `libcxx` to the `RDEPENDS` of your recipe.

c.f.: https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/39646/

However, not sure if it wouldn't be better anyway to recompile Tokbox if you have the sources.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried to add meta-clang but it is not compatible with my Yocto Dunfell version. Is there any other way to do it? I only have a pre-compiled library .so file as a source.

Comment: Checkout the dunfell branch.